# Array transform having failable initialiser

Tags: swift

I am using Swift 1.2 in Xcode 6.3.1
Following is my `Person` struct

```
struct Person {
    let age: Int
    init?(age: Int) {                   //Failable init
        if age > 100 { return nil }
        self.age = age
    }
}
```

I am having a list of ages against which I have to make Person Objects.

---

I have made playground file.

```
let arr = Array(1...150) //Sample set of ages against which Person is created
var personList: [Person]!
```

and

```
personList = arr.map({ (val: Int) -> Person? in
    return Person(age: val)        //Makes object of type Person?
}).filter {
    $0 != nil
}.map {
    return $0!
}
```

Here I have uses `map - filter - map` because the first map invokes failable intializer, (hence it returns Person?) and `personList` is of type `[Person]`.
Hence second function filters all the non nil objects and third map forcefully opens to optional therby making Person? to Person.

Is there a more easy/readable way out ? Chaining map-filter-map definitely seems to be an overkill for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use flatMap to get rid of any nils in the array, [this tutorial](http://alisoftware.github.io/swift/2015/10/11/thinking-in-swift-4/) discusses the method in length, but the following will work best:

`let personList = arr.flatMap { Person(age: $0) }`

Answer (score 3):

*Note:* This answer was given for Swift 1.2, the current
version at the time the question was posted. Since Swift 2 there is a better solution, see @Jeremie's answer.

---

I don't know of a built-in function that combines `filter()`
and `map()`. You can write the code slightly more compact using
the shorthand argument `$0` in *all* closures:

```
let personList = arr.map { Person(age: $0) }
    .filter { $0 != nil }
    .map { $0! }
```

Of course you can define your own extension method which maps the
array elements and keeps only the non-nil results:

```
extension Array {
    func optmap<U>(transform: T -> U?) -> [U] {
        var result : [U] = []
        for elem in self {
            if let mapped = transform(elem) {
                result.append(mapped)
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

and then use it as

```
let personList = arr.optmap { Person(age: $0) }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `compactMap` which is better that `flatMap` in this case to remove any nils in the array:

```
let personList = arr.compactMap { Person(age: $0) }
```

The [Swift document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2950916-compactmap) declared:

> Returns an array containing the non-nil results of calling the given
>   transformation with each element of this sequence.